# Is there any reason anyone would prefer appending/removing external parts over excluding/including collections in an object generator?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I bumped into this NFT generating script where a guy just keeps on deleting everything->adding new random objects from external files->rendering->deleting everything->repeat.

And I started wondering: is there a reason to do that and not just have one larger file and just include/exclude collections with separate parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a potentially valid reason: the second approach results in a much larger blend file while the first approach allows the blend file to remain relatively small.

Whether it's the reason for the script you bumped into is impossible to say without asking the script's author.  Often the reasons for such thing come down to 'it was the first approach I thought of', or 'I already knew how to do it this way', et cetera.

Comment: A NFT author using whatever hacky way they first thought of to generate thousands of renders as quick as possible? *surprised pikachu face*